# "Member declaration not found" in a nested template class in C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, class, templates

I've written a small template class in C++ representing a priority queue.
However, I keep getting a "Member declaration not found" for all the functions I've written which are part of a nested class inside the template PriorityQueue class that are supposed to return a new instance of that same object.

The problematic code segment is the following:

```
template<typename PriorityType, typename DataType>
class PriorityQueue<PriorityType, DataType>::iterator {
public:
    // Default constructor
    iterator(ElementType& element) : m_element(&element) {}

    // Operator overloads
    DataType& operator*() const;
    IteratorType operator+(const IteratorType& other) const;
    iterator& operator++();
    iterator operator++(int);
    bool operator==(const iterator& it) const;
    bool operator!=(const iterator& it) const;
};

// Prefix Increment (++i) operator overload
template<typename PriorityType, typename DataType>
typename PriorityQueue<PriorityType, DataType>::iterator& PriorityQueue<
    PriorityType, DataType>::iterator::operator++() {
    this->m_element =
            (PriorityQueueElement<PriorityType, DataType>) *(this->m_element).m_next;
    return *this;
}
```

In this case, Eclipse displays a "Member declaration not found" error for the operator++ overload, even though it's defined in the public part of the class.

What is the problem?

NOTE: This is only part of the code, all types that are not declared in this segment of code are defined in the source file.

Comment: Does the code compile?  I can't tell if you're asking about a compiler error or just an Eclipse message.

Comment: Does your `PriorityQueue<...>` declare the nested class `iterator`? Why only a forward-declaration?

Comment: `IteratorType` and `ElementType` and `PriorityQueueElement` are undefined. You also do not define `m_element`. Is this real code?

Comment: As I added, this is part of a real code I'm working on (it's simply very long). PriorityQueue<> declares the iterator and all types are defined.

Comment: if you are using a++ you need to add implementation of operator++(int) too. your code seems correct I make a simple working example of it : https://ideone.com/Csi4g3

Comment: Thank you, xyz! Seeing that this part of code compiles on ideone makes me believe that this is a temporary incorrect error thrown by Eclipse, so I'll keep working on the code expecting the error to disappear when it compiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing how user xyz was able to write a working example on ideone.com, this is probably a temporary error that should disappear when everything compiles and is working.